# BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notes()

Tags: laravel-5

i'm getting the above error while following laravel from scratch tutorials from laracats.com,
bellow is full error message

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notes()

```
in Builder.php line 2345
at Builder->__call('notes', array())
at Builder->notes()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'notes'), array()) in Builder.php line 1426
at Builder->__call('notes', array())
at Builder->notes()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'notes'), array()) in Model.php line 3505
at Model->__call('notes', array()) in NotesController.php line 19
at Note->notes() in NotesController.php line 19
at NotesController->store(object(Request), object(Card))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(NotesController), 'store'), array(object(Request), 'card' => object(Card))) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('store', array(object(Request), 'card' => object(Card))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(NotesController), object(Route), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(NotesController), object(Route), object(Request), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\NotesController', 'store') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('/home/archie/public_html/my_blog/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

My NotesController is as below

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Card;
use App\Note;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class NotesController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, Card $card)
    {


        $note = new Note;

        $note->body = $request->body;
        $note->notes()->save($note);

        return back;


}
}
```

Card Model is as below

```
 namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Card extends Model
{
   public function notes()
   {
    return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
   }

   public function path()
   {
    return '/cards/'.$this->id;
   }
}
```

Comment: please add your NotesController also

Comment: Did you migrate your Tables already? What is the name associated with your Eloquent Model: `Notes` or `Note`? Does the Model exist? You can create it with: `php artisan make:model Note` or `php artisan make:model Notes`. Try also running: `composer dump-autoload` on the command line.

Comment: @Poiz i used php artisan make:model Note

Comment: @RavishaHesh i have added the NotesController above

Comment: Same error I am also facing instead of __call('notes')    Ny error is 
at Builder->__call('appends', array(null))

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Laravel from scratch tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/8) you are trying to save note into a card. So you should use `$card->notes()->sav‌​e($note);` instead of `$note->notes()->save($note);`

Comment: Did you defined notes() relationship on Card model?

Comment: please add Card model also

Comment: see above for Card Model

Comment: your Card model looks ok, what's the error did you get from `$card->notes()->sav‌​e($note);`

Comment: the error is     BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sav‌​e()

Comment: @Archie everything looks correct.  So we need to go through the stack trace to identify the issue.  So can you update the question with stack trace of current error. (if you didn't noticed,  it's different from previous one)